# Convert decimal value to comma for pandas to excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to save a dataframe consisting of values with decimal value separated by dots to an excel file. In the excel file the values should be shown with a comma.
I know that I can include decimal = ',' when using dataframe.to_csv. But is there a comparable solution for dataframe.to_excel?

Here is my code. Df1 is a dataframe:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(topics1, index=topicnumber, columns= wordnumber)
with pandas.ExcelWriter(topics1_speicherpfad_excel) as writer:
     df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "Topics")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my question is obsolete. Excel recognizes that these are decimal characters and automatically converts them to the specified format. I close the question with that. The code in the question already solves the "problem" by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could also turn them into strings and use `replace`:

```
df1.wordnumber = df1.wordnumber.astype(str)
df1.wordnumber = df1.wordnumber.apply(lambda x: x.replace('.',',')
```

Then write to excel.